# What does the word occupancy mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The day for changing from one occupancy to the next was on a Saturday.

As far as I know, occupancy doesn't refer to a place but the use or the period of time you use a place, and it's uncountable. 
I can't work out the meaning. 
By the way it's longman's sentence example with occupancy.

Comment: That sentence doesn't make sense, I think you've misquoted it, it should actually be "The day for changing from one occupancy to the next was on a Saturday." It could mean that Saturday is the day when current occupants move out and new occupants move in.

Comment: You're right! Good thing I mentioned the source! And how come it's countable in this sense? I thought it can never be countable based on the dictionary definition.

Comment: Please use sources to support your findings, where did you get the idea that occupancy *only* refers to a **period** of time or how long you use a place? The definition of occupancy in dictionaries is also something along the lines of “*the action or fact of occupying a place.*”

Comment: Note also [occupancy (s.)](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/occupancy) is both countable and uncountable, its plural being *occupancies*.

Comment: If you check longman dictionary this example is presented for this definition "someone’s use of a building, hotel, or other space, for living or working in, or the period during which they live or work there" and it says (uncountable). Can you tell me what your impression of this sentence is?

Comment: @Nastaran Y I think WS2 already provides an impression for this sentence:- “ **However, if I describe the period during which one person occupies the building as an occupancy, and each subsequent instance an occupancy. Then each of those "occupancies" can be counted.**“

Comment: Replace *The day for changing from one occupancy to the next was on a Saturday.* with *The day for changing from one occupancy to the next was Saturday.*.  As written OP's sentence suggest that a day occurred on a day, which is some kind of semantic oddity.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark If you say "...was on Saturday", with no article, nor with "on" then by implication it is a specific Saturday, either the next coming Saturday, or the Saturday following some reference to another day - e.g. *As I was to be at church on the Sunday, the job needed completing by Saturday". However I do agree with what I think is your main point, that having used the word "day" already, the sentence as currently written sounds awkward. I might have written "Occupancies were always changed on a Saturday" - if that is what is meant.

Comment: It is very obvious what the sentence is supposed to mean. Yes we can say it's clumsy and awkward and rubbish. But it is perfectly clear what the clumsy author *wants* it to mean. If you can think of several conflicting readings, please list them all so we can have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a sense in which it is countable.

If I say *Fire damage has made occupancy of the building impossible.*, **that is NOT countable.**

However, if I describe the period during which one person occupies the building as ***an occupancy***, and each subsequent instance *an occupancy*. **Then each of those "occupancies" can be counted.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you tell me what your impression of this sentence is? "The day for changing from one occupancy to the next was on a Saturday "

Comment: I agree with this answer and would say that the only grammatical problem with the sentence is *on* (as @HighPerformanceMark has already commented). - so I think  *the day for changing from one occupancy to the next was Saturday* is grammatical, but it strikes me as awkward. Where did you get it from?

Comment: @JD2000 *On a Saturday" is potentially different to "on Saturday". The latter could mean "this coming Saturday (one time only)". There is nothing whatever wrong with "on a Saturday".

Comment: I have no problem with *on a Saturday* in itself, as in *occupancy would change on a Saturday* - what I said was that it didn't work in the original sentence, which has *the day... was ON a Saturday*. For me you can't say *our wedding day was on a Saturday* or *bin collection day was on a Thursday*. It has to be *we got married o a Saturday* or *the bins were collected on a Thursday*.

Comment: @JD2000 Yes. I accept your point -see my comment above to *High Performance Mark*.

Answer (score 0):

The [Longman’s dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/occupancy) you consulted already explains the countable and uncountable sense of occupancy:

noun [uncountable] formal

> [1] the number of people who stay, work, or live in a room or building at  the same time
>
> single/multiple occupancy 
>   single occupancy room rates
>
> e.g. Hotels in Tokyo enjoy over 90% occupancy. [***uncountable example***]

> [2] someone’s use of a building, hotel, or other space, for living or working in, or the period during which they live or work there
>
> e.g. The day for changing from one occupancy to the next was on a Saturday. [***countable example***]

Sense 2, therefore must be the “countable” sense, although it fails to **directly** mention this, the example for number 2 shows this, and other dictionaries mentions its countable sense.

Comment: You see I checked oxford and longman and both don't explicitly mention that occupancy can be used as a countable noun yet longman used it as a countable noun in one example which confused me but thanks to the answers I got to my question I know it can be countable in one sense. I'd appreciate if you could tell me what the sentence I posted means